# Cross module optimizations in GHC

Tags: performance, haskell, optimization, haskell-criterion

I have a non-recursive function to calculate longest common subsequence that seems to perform well (`ghc 7.6.1`, compiled with `-O2 -fllvm` flags) if I measure it with `Criterion` in the same module. On the other hand, if I convert the function into a module, export just that function (as recommended [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/GHC#Modules_and_separate_compilation)), and then measure again with Criterion, I get ~2x slowdown (which goes away if I move the criterion test back to the module where function is defined). I tried marking the function with `INLINE` pragma which didn't make any difference in cross-module performance measurements.

It seems to me that GHC might be doing a strictness analysis that works well when the function and the main (from which the function is reachable) are in the same module, but not when they are split across. I would appreciate pointers on how to modularize the function so that it performs well when called from other modules. The code in question is too big to paste here - you can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0a8d7ca2c2a81b415f02) if you want to try it out. A small example of what I am trying to do is below (with snippets of code):

```
-- Function to find longest common subsequence given unboxed vectors a and b
-- It returns indices of LCS in a and b
lcs :: (U.Unbox a, Eq a) => Vector a -> Vector a -> (Vector Int,Vector Int)
lcs a b | (U.length a > U.length b) = lcsh b a True
        | otherwise = lcsh a b False

-- This section below measures performance of lcs function - if I move it to 
-- a different module, performance degrades ~2x - mean goes from ~1.25us to ~2.4us
-- on my test machine
{-- 
config :: Config
config = defaultConfig  { cfgSamples = ljust 100 }

a = U.fromList ['a'..'j'] :: Vector Char
b = U.fromList ['a'..'k'] :: Vector Char

suite :: [Benchmark]
suite = [
          bench "lcs 10" $ whnf (lcs a) b
        ]

main :: IO()
main = defaultMainWith config (return ()) suite
--}
```

Comment: Try out the INLINEABLE instead. It might work better.

Comment: @Carl, tried it for lcs function. Still the same.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that when it's all in one module, GHC can specialize the type variable `a` to `Char` since it's never used with any other type, eliminating the type class overhead. You could try playing around with the `SPECIALIZE` pragma (or just change it to `Char` manually) and see if that has any effect.

Comment: I've seen the same thing myself several times, and each time I've thought "there oughta be a program that transforms a multi-module Haskell program into single-module one and benchmarks the two". It would make it easier to know if one should consider fiddling with `SPEICIALIZE`/`INLINE`/`INLINEABLE`. Does such a thing exist? It should essentially boil down to name mangling, right?

Comment: I still wish there was a pragma to tell GHC to specialize a function based on the *value* of a particular argument if it was known at compile time. That'd be a huge help with high-performance use of higher-order functions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[hammar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98117/hammar) [is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908539/cross-module-optimizations-in-ghc#comment24406068_16908539), the important issue is that the compiler can see the type that `lcs` is used at **at the same time as it can see the code**, so it can specialise the code to that particular type.

If the compiler doesn't know the type at which the code shall be used, it cannot but only produce polymorphic code. And that is bad for performance - I'm rather surprised it's only a ~2× difference here. Polymorphic code means that for many operations a type-class lookup is needed, and that at least makes it impossible to inline the looked-up function or constant-fold sizes [e.g. for unboxed array/vector access].

You cannot obtain comparable performance to the one-module case with implementation and use in separate modules without making the code that needs specialising visible at the use site (or, if you know the needed types at the implementation site, specialising there, `{-# SPECIALISE foo :: Char -> Int, foo :: Bool -> Integer #-}` etc.).

Making the code visible at the use-site is usually done by exposing the unfolding in the interface file via marking the function `{-# INLINABLE #-}`.

> I tried marking the function with `INLINE` pragma which didn't make any difference in cross-module performance measurements.

Marking only

```
lcs :: (U.Unbox a, Eq a) => Vector a -> Vector a -> (Vector Int,Vector Int)
lcs a b | (U.length a > U.length b) = lcsh b a True
        | otherwise = lcsh a b False
```

`INLINE` or `INLINABLE` doesn't make a difference of course, that function is trivial, and the compiler exposes its unfolding anyway, since it's so small. Even if its unfolding wasn't exposed, the difference would not be measurable.

You need to expose the unfoldings of the functions doing the actual work too, at least that of the polymorphic ones, `lcsh`, `findSnakes`, `gridWalk` and `cmp` (`cmp` is the one that's crucial here, but the others are necessary to 1. see that `cmp` is needed, 2. call the specialised `cmp` from them).

Making those `INLINABLE`, the difference between the separate-module case

```
$ ./diffBench 
warming up
estimating clock resolution...
mean is 1.573571 us (320001 iterations)
found 2846 outliers among 319999 samples (0.9%)
  2182 (0.7%) high severe
estimating cost of a clock call...
mean is 40.54233 ns (12 iterations)

benchmarking lcs 10
mean: 1.628523 us, lb 1.618721 us, ub 1.638985 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 51.75533 ns, lb 47.04237 ns, ub 58.45611 ns, ci 0.950
variance introduced by outliers: 26.787%
variance is moderately inflated by outliers
```

and the single-module case

```
$ ./oneModule 
warming up
estimating clock resolution...
mean is 1.726459 us (320001 iterations)
found 2092 outliers among 319999 samples (0.7%)
  1608 (0.5%) high severe
estimating cost of a clock call...
mean is 39.98567 ns (14 iterations)

benchmarking lcs 10
mean: 1.523183 us, lb 1.514157 us, ub 1.533071 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 48.48541 ns, lb 44.43230 ns, ub 55.04251 ns, ci 0.950
variance introduced by outliers: 26.791%
variance is moderately inflated by outliers
```

is bearably small.

Comment: good points. I forgot about specialization when trying to analyze this.